# "The metric names were not found" when deploying microsoft.insights/metricAlerts

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy a MetricAlert with my Traffic Manager Profile and I always get {
  "Code": "BadRequest",
  "Message": "The metric names were not found ."
}

I'm trying to use the Endpoint Status by Endpoint metric and having no luck. Any idea what the correct metric name would be or how I can find it?

[image]

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "microsoft.insights/metricAlerts",
            "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
            "name": "All-PPE-Endpoints-Down",
            "location": "global",
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "Alert-AllEndpointsDown"
            },
            "properties": {
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "actionGroupId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', 'TDFFCEmailActionGroup')]"
                    }
                ],
                "criteria": {
                    "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.MultipleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria",
                    "allOf": [
                        {
                            "criterionType": "DynamicThresholdCriterion",
                            "name": "1st criterion",
                            "metricName": "Endpoint Status by Endpoint(Platform)",
                            "dimensions": [],
                            "operator": "LessThan",
                            "alertSensitivity": "Medium",
                            "failingPeriods": {
                                "numberOfEvaluationPeriods": "4",
                                "minFailingPeriodsToAlert": "3"
                            },
                            "timeAggregation": "Maximum"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "description": "All endpoints are not responding to ping",
                "enabled": true,
                "evaluationFrequency": "PT5M",
                "scopes": [
                    "/subscriptions/84eba200-00a9-41d3-9916-d63b2e25da02/resourceGroups/tdff5-rg-ppe/providers/Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles/tdfppegas"
                ],
                "severity": 3,
                "windowSize": "PT5M"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metrics documentation webpage which describes all of the built-in metrics can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftnetworktrafficmanagerprofiles

In this case, the key I was looking for was **ProbeAgentCurrentEndpointStateByProfileResourceId**